# Problema com migrate do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Acabei de instalar o Laravel no meu pc para aprender um pouco. Porém estou tento um pequeno problema ao usar o `migrate`.
Sempre que tento utilizar o `migrate`, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>         SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'clients' already exists (SQL: create table `clients` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `responsible` varchar(255)   not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `phone` varchar(255) not null, `address` text not null, `obs` text not nul  l, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_  ci)

Ele acaba não gerando as novas `migrations` que criei, porém, quando mudo a data de uma `migration` para uma data anterior, ele funciona.

> [image: Erro no migrate]

Comment: A tabela `clients` já existe, por isso ele não consegue rodar a migration de criar a tabela `clients`, apague a tabela do seu banco que funcionara normalmente.

Comment: Tem que ver o que você fez! Tipo talvez nome de tabelas que já existe, porque `clients` deve ser você que criou? Você por acaso mudou alguma coisas nos `migrate` que já vem no Laravel?

Comment: Não mudei nada. A tabela existe pq eu mudei a data e o migrate funcionou. Mas antes de eu mudar a data, ele simplesmente não funcionava. Era como se ele só contasse 'users'

Comment: No Laravel caso houver algum erro na tabela a ser criada o *migrate* não consegue dar um *rollback* delete o banco de dados e crie novamente e rode *php artisan migrate*. Se tiver algum erro irá te mostrar em qual arquivo está o erro de sua migração.